# Tags for age/maturity level questions (i.e. less violent game for young players)

Tags: discussion, tags

What would be a good tag for questions about game maturity level type questions?

EDIT:

I've seen some people start using kids, perhaps kids teens adults are simple and sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, kids/teens/adults is basically G/PG/R ratings I think. But without the pretension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dunno... what purpose would this serve but to attract the attention of those who aren't supposed to look at that material?

I could understand a [NAFW] tag but any attempt to mark off questions as forbidden will only attract those who shouldn't be there...

I like kids/teen/adult as it more implies who would be most interested rather than who can/should view content.

Answer (score 0):

I would say just [age] should be sufficient.

Comment: that seems vague, maybe age-appropriate? but that's rather long.

Comment: [player-age] perhaps?